# An alternative to the Super key on an old keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, emacs

I've got a classic [M-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_M_keyboard) IBM keyboard that I want to put to a use.  However, it does not have a <kbd>Windows</kbd> (a.k.a <kbd>Super</kbd>) key, that I use for many windows-manager-related shortcuts.  On top of it, I use Emacs, so many <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts are already taken.  I also can't use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as a modifier, since that it is taken for switching between languages.

What keyboard shortcuts would you recommend me for the windows manager (Gnome w. Emerald), taking into account these limitations (no <kbd>Super</kbd> key, can't remap <kbd>Caps</kbd>, and must not collide with frequent Emacs shortcuts)?

Comment: Do you have a preferred key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you already use right <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

You could map it to the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key in Gnome settings:

- System->Preferences->Keyboard
- Layouts
- Options...
- Alt/Win key behavior
- Left Alt is swapped with Left Win

Or you could map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, and choose another shortcut for changing languages.

In the same control panel:

- CapsLock key behaviour
- Make CapsLock an additional Super

  (or Make CapsLock an additional Hyper)

and then:

- Key(s) to change layout
- *too many options to mention*

Common choices include:

- Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

but being an `Emacs` user, I would suggest the `Both Ctrl keys together` option.

---

If those options are insufficient, you will need to use `xmodmap`.

You could map Right <kbd>Control</kbd> to <kbd>Windows</kbd> at the shell like this:

```
xmodmap -e 'remove control = Control_R'
xmodmap -e 'add Mod4 = Control_R'
```

Depending on your system, you can probably also put the equivalent settings in `.Xmodmap`, e.g.

**.Xmodmap**

```
remove control = Control_R'
add Mod4 = Control_R'
```

If you'd rather use `xmodmap` than the Gnome control panel, you can change `Control_R` to something else, for instance right <kbd>Alt</kbd> is either `Alt_R` or `ISO_Level3_Shift`, depending on your keyboard settings, e.g.

```
xmodmap -e 'remove ISO_Level3_Shift = Mod5'
xmodmap -e 'add Mod4 = ISO_Level3_Shift'
```

works for me.

Comment: These are good options - Right Alt as super might work.  I'll give it a swing.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Note that you'll probably need the `xmodmap` version, and that it could be `ISO_Level3_Shift` or `Alt_R`.

Comment: Capslock options no longer seem to be there in Ubuntu 18?

Comment: on ubuntu 20 `System->Preferences->Keyboard` is no more, there is `Keyboard Shortcuts` now? i used `xmodmap` and worked just fine though :)

Answer (score 0):

From normal desktop usage I can attest to the fact that 'alt' is used far less frequently than 'ctrl' (unless you use 'alt' for menubar navigation). Since I am assuming you have only 'shift', 'ctrl', and 'alt', I would pair 'alt' and 'shift' together - Your thumb could press down 'alt' while your pinky would press 'shift'. This kind of motion is extremely easy for me to use. Also, there are never any shortcuts calling for those two modifiers at the same time.

I don't use emacs but I'm pretty sure that it uses 'alt' as the main modifier. If so, I guess this runs the risk of conflicting. Thus, the only other usable alternative would be 'ctrl'+'shift'. Of course, if you have one of those context menu buttons then that could work wonderfully (depending on the position).

Answer (score 0):

You can create or locate a keymap which treats left and right control or alt keys differently.  I didn't see an easy way to do it from the Gnome panel.

Look at the options for xmodmap.