# How do I change the shortcut key to launch the dash

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

I'm using a Logitech Cordless Mediaboard and since it doesn't have a win key, I need to change the shortcut for launching the dash.

I'm not looking to assign Alt Gr as win key or any other key. I want to change the shortcut key to launch the dash, for example Alt+z or Alt Gr

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this may help.  I have an old Thinkpad with no win key, so I made the caps-lock key  a win key.  In addition to providing a win key, it also disables the useless caps-lock key so it won't accidentally get pressed and mess me up sometimes.  It's easy to do in the keyboard layout settings.

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key - at least the answer should help!

Answer (score 6):

Go to **Configuration Editor > / > apps > compiz-1 > plugins > unityshell > screen0 > options** and edit the `Show launcher` string to `<Alt>Z`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist on 12.04. Any ideas?

Comment: Aha, I had to install gconf-editor.

Comment: @TedMielczarek glad to here that you've resolved it yourself, also note that these days some of the `gconf` entries are being migrated to `gsettings` or `dconf-edior`

Comment: This didn't work on 15.10, this did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key

Answer (score 4):

This should work on Ubuntu 15.10:

- Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager].
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `about:config` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Select the "Launcher" tab, and change the keyboard shortcut for "Key to show the Dash, Launcher and Help Overlay".

  [image: Screenshot of CompizConfig Settings Manager]

Comment: Under Ubuntu 16.04, this solution worked for me but with two variations. The package is found under in the Ubuntu Software Center under "CompizConfig Settings Manager". When the application is launched go to Category > Desktop > Ubuntu Unity Plugin, then the Launcher tab.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Sytem Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts Tab

Under the Launchers category, look for the Search action and edit the accelerator.

Comment: Didn't work for me on ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop, open the *System Settings* window. (If you need to locate it, search for `Settings` in the `Dash`.)

Keyboard shortcuts are under the `Shortcuts` tab of the `Keyboard` settings. However, I did not find a shortcut for the `Dash`.

Another way to go is to select *Keyboard Layout* and press the <kbd>Options</kbd> button in the lower left corner.

As suggested in a comment, one possibility is under `Caps Lock key behavior`. Also look at alternate mappings under `Alt/Win key behavior` or `Ctrl key position`.

You may also find the answer to this question useful.
[An alternative to the Super key on an old keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/q/18120/52923)

While not (I think) providing an answer to your question, this community wiki question may provide additional information which you may also be interested in.
[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/28086/52923)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the dash:
   [image]
2. Type `keyboard` and open it
3. go to the <kbd>shortcuts</kbd> menu

Now you can edit all keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Except the one for dash, it seems (disabling the "Search" shortcut didn't work for me)