# How to emulate the super key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, shortcuts

I use an extremely old retro-keyboard.... " TVS 101.PC-XT"
This keyboard has only 101 keys (AlphaNumeric, NumPad, FunctionKeys); 
And I don't intent to change it for I am very comfortable with it !

Since this keyboard **doesn't have a super key** (windows Key), 
I am looking for some way out that I can emulate this.
I am looking for a shortcut key combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SysRQ</kbd>
which might behave as <kbd>[image: the windows logo key]</kbd> Key when used in combination altogether?

NOTE: I've already [gone through](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18120/an-alternative-to-the-super-key-on-an-old-keyboard) this, however this in not the workout in my case since I don't use gnome (no chance for Gnome settings).. I am on *Ubuntu minimal + cinnamon*..
I am also unable to locate the `xmodmap` commands to achieve this !

Comment: Please add the output of `xmodmap -pke | less`.  Maybe I can find the right keys :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I would do it without `xmodmap`.  I'm not sure if I can emulate the <kbd>SysRQ</kbd> key this way, but it should work for other keys.

## Step One

Install `xbindkeys` and `xte`:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
```

Now we need to find the bindings of the keys you want to use as <kbd>Super</kbd>.
Run `xbindkeys -k` and press the keys you want.  The output should look something like this:

```
    m:0x15 + c:110
Control+Shift+Mod2 + Home
```

(I used <kbd>Home</kbd> because I can't use <kbd>SysRQ</kbd> on this computer since it requires <kbd>FN</kbd> to access it).

## Step Two

Create the `xbindkeys` configuration file:

```
touch $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Now open the file so we can edit it:

```
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

Add this to the bottom of the file:

```
"xte 'key Super_L'"
 m:0x15 + c:110
Control+Shift+Mod2 + Home
```

Save the file.

Restart the computer.  The keys you chose earlier should now act as <kbd>Super</kbd> when you press them.