# Return to desktop from software / game

Tags: games

When I launch an application / a game and while I'm using it, it hangs up and I can't quit to return to desktop by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or something like this.

I want to return to desktop, open a terminal and kill the app / game.

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open a [TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

It'll look like a terminal, just login as usual with your login name and password.

Then two options to stop the game:

- type `ps -aef` to identify the process id of your game (it should be one of the last entries) and kill it with `kill -9 <pid>`
- type `pkill <game name>`

Once the game process is killed, you can reopen the Desktop session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. (Note that opening a TTY did not stop or close your active sesssion)

Comment: May be better use `kill -15` instead

Comment: @c0rp maybe if the game is still responsive, but I agree that sending SIGTERM before SIGKILL is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ubuntu "Desktop" shortcut. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on your keyboard.

Comment: What if one doesn't have a "super" key on the keyboard?

Comment: The 'Super' key is (usually) the Windows key on a Windows keyboard, or the Command key on a Mac. There's also [these options](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18120/an-alternative-to-the-super-key-on-an-old-keyboard) if your keyboard lacks any kind of Super key